# How to block gTalk on any workstation

Tags: firewall, blocking, google-talk

I want to block the "Google Talk" application on a workstation, without uninstalling it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?  Each OS has different ways of doing things, including firewall configuration (you'll either be blocking the TCP/UDP/ICMP ports this application uses, or just preventing it specifically from connecting to the internet at all).

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to block the [ports or the  domain name at your firewall or route](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?answer=27930)r - the former could be a pain - you'd need to block ports 5222 and 443 - the later is a standard port used for https so it can be a bit of a pain. Alternately block the domain name talk.google.com using hosts.txt or at your firewall

I have no idea if this will block web access via gmail though.

(yes i know the google link is for unblocking gtalk, but blocking is unblocking in reverse)